# php mysql query with integer as value error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can someone please tell me why the first sql query works but the second thrown an error. I've not been able to find out why the integer value causes it to break.

Works:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = $uname AND pass = $pword";
```

Errors:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = $uname AND firstLogin = 1";

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND firstLogin = 1' at line 1
```

Also if there's some additional enlightenment you have to offer im all ears.

EDITED TO SHOW FUNCTIONAL CONNECTION Using PDO:

```
<?php
    $uname = "userNameToSearchBy";

//PDO connection string 
    $user_name = "dbUsername";
    $pass_word = "dbPass";
    $database = "sdName";
    $server = "dbServer";
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$server.";dbname=".$database.";", $user_name, $pass_word);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName=? AND firstLogin=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($uname, 1));
    //Returns the rows from thge database that match the query
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //Shows the number of rows returned
    $message = $stmt->rowCount();   
?>
<body>
<?php echo $message ?>
</body>
```

Outputs number of rows that match the sql criteria

Comment: Are you sure the first one works? If `userName` and/or `pass` are strings of any type, then they need to be surrounded by `'`. That at least appears why the 2nd one wouldn't work and that same problem exists in the first example.

Comment: What is the data type of the field `firstLogin` in your table?

Comment: tinyInt(1) value can be 0 or default of 1

The first line doesn't seem to be throwing an error, and the code continues dotn past 2 if statements that use its output

Comment: try this  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = '".$uname."' AND pass = $pword";

Comment: @boyd the first query seems to be working and returning a result that can be used in `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);` however only the second throws the error

Comment: for the second query try  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = '".$uname."' AND firstLogin = 1";

Comment: @boyd I get the following error  with that line:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /hermes/bosweb25b/b807/sl.kwolmara/public_html/Collab.php on line 84 `

Comment: You're looking for something like prepared statements offered by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  I'm surprised no one has posted the typical lecture about not using mysql_* yet.

Comment: @Brad Koch I came across another posting mentioning PDO and mysqli? but wasn't able to get it to work. This is my first real venture into php beyond a basic hello world, so im not too familiar with teh language yet.

Comment: @Reahreic, that's fine!  Sounds like a great opportunity to ask a question about what didn't work with PDO instead.  I'll try to add more detail in my answer to get you started.

Comment: @Brad Koch: It might have been that my database conenction strings needed changing.


`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /hermes/bosweb25b/b807/sl.kwolmara/public_html/test.php on line 9 `

Comment: That means the connection attempt failed, and therefore the return value was not a PDO object.  The odd part is I would have expected an Exception before that error occurred, so there might be something else wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop your `quote_smart()` function, the deprecated mysql_ functions, and use [PDO prepared statements instead](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  That should resolve your problem while improving the security and quality of your codebase.

There's a standard comment that gives more detail on this, check out the PDO tutorial at the end in particular:

> Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the **[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)**? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I'm trying this in an empty .php doc to ensure nothing else gets in the way:
 `$uname = "kwolmarans";
 $user_name = "nameHidden";
 $pass_word = "passwordHidden";
 $database = "dbName";
 $server = "kwolmara.startlogicmysql.com";
 try{
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$server.";dbname=".$database.";charset=UTF-8", $user_name, $pass_word);
 }catch(PDOException $ex){
  //
 }
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName=? AND firstLogin=?");
 $stmt->execute(array($uname, 1));
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: This is the error that follows:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /hermes/bosweb25b/b807/sl.kwolmara/public_html/test.php on line 13`

Line 13 is:
`$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName=? AND firstLogin=?");`

Comment: The connection is failing.  You're catching the exception, and so the error details are not being displayed.

Comment: Here's the uncaught error message:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set UTF-8 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)' in /hermes/bosweb25b/b807/sl.kwolmara/public_html/test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /hermes/bosweb25b/b807/sl.kwolmara/public_html/test.php(8): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=kwol...', 'usernameHidden', 'passwordHidden') #1 {main} thrown in /hermes/bosweb25b/b807/sl.kwolmara/public_html/test.php on line 8 `

Comment: It clearly doesn't like the `charset=UTF-8`.  I'm not prepared to elaborate on why you are getting that error; that would be a good new question.  I would think removing that declaration should be a sufficient solution to avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo your sql statement

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = $uname AND firstLogin = 1";
echo($SQL);
```

Something is probably wrong with `$uname`. If it is empty you get

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = AND firstLogin = 1";
```

which has syntax error.

You can also put quote around `$uname` like this

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = '$uname' AND firstLogin = 1";
```

If `$uname` also has single quote, that can cause problem too

Comment: Echo Result:
`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = 'kwolmarans' AND firstLogin = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting $uname... or passing the value through to mysql_real_escape()

Comment: All my input fields go through this function:
`function quote_smart($value, $handle) {
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
   }
   if (!is_numeric($value)) {
       $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
   }
   return $value;
}`

Comment: Oh. What type is firstLogin? Also, ensure $uname is in scope.

Comment: It's of type tinyint(1) with a default set to 1

Comment: what does quote_smart() return on a blank name?

Comment: It returns these two characters with a "" string: `''`

Comment: Yikes. I'd need to see the actual value of $SQL in your fail case.

Comment: Echo Result: SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = 'kwolmarans' AND firstLogin = 1

Comment: That'll work, if what everything else you've said works. Good luck. Try pasting that line into a MySQL client **(NOT PHPMyAdmin)**.